# Looking for a short story, probably late '70's early 80's science fiction re driving banned car

Tags: story-identification

An old man starts up an old gas guzzler car that he had secreted away after cars were banned. He steals(?) some gas and takes it out on the highway at night. Lots of imagery about headlights on the road and the thrill of going cruising. Thanks!

Comment: I think that story was in a paperback full of short stories that was possibly called "car stories". In the same story the person is hunted by exhaust sniffers and police that know someone is driving a car with an external combustion engine which is totally illegal. I also cannot find that book but loved it I think it was a late 70's early 80's publication.

Comment: @71Bacon [Car Sinister](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?6099)?

Answer (score 13):

It is just possible that you are recalling the [Rush song *Red Barchetta*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Barchetta) from the album *Moving Pictures*.

Failing that, the song is based at some level on a story "A Nice Morning Drive" by Richard Foster from 1973 ([also available on-line](http://www.mgexp.com/article/nice-drive.html) from a source that looks like it may respect copyright).

---

Lyrics of the song:

> My uncle has a country place
>   That no one knows about
>   He says it used to be a farm
>   Before the Motor Law
>   And on Sundays I elude the eyes
>   And hop the Turbine Freight
>   To far outside the Wire
>   Where my white-haired uncle waits
>
> Jump to the ground
>   As the Turbo slows to cross the borderline
>   Run like the wind
>   As excitement shivers up and down my spine
>   Down in his barn
>   My uncle preserved for me an old machine
>   For fifty odd years
>   To keep it as new has been his dearest dream
>
> I strip away the old debris
>   That hides a shining car
>   A brilliant red Barchetta
>   From a better vanished time
>   I fire up the willing engine
>   Responding with a roar
>   Tires spitting gravel
>   I commit my weekly crime
>
> Wind
>   In my hair
>   Shifting and drifting
>   Mechanical music
>   Adrenaline surge...
>
> Well-weathered leather
>   Hot metal and oil
>   The scented country air
>   Sunlight on chrome
>   The blur of the landscape
>   Every nerve aware
>
> Suddenly ahead of me
>   Across the mountainside
>   A gleaming alloy air car
>   Shoots towards me, two lanes wide
>   I spin around with shrieking tires
>   To run the deadly race
>   Go screaming through the valley
>   As another joins the chase
>
> Drive like the wind
>   Straining the limits of machine and man
>   Laughing out loud with fear and hope
>   I've got a desperate plan
>   At the one-lane bridge
>   I leave the giants stranded at the riverside
>   Race back to the farm
>   To dream with my uncle at the fireside

[Lyrics found here](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/rush/redbarchetta.html)

Comment: This really sounds like "A Nice Morning Drive" or "Red Barchetta".  But one detail is off... the gas guzzlers were the "gleaming alloy air cars" that were "two lanes wide" in the Rush song, or just plain huge gas guzzlers with CB radios in the story.  The protagonist was driving a sports car, which is hardly an economy car but not really a gas guzzler, but the original story made a point about safety regulations having made cars so heavy that they were unwieldy gas guzzlers.

Answer (score 2):

I looked for answer to same question myself; look here: 
[classic short story in anthology.Driving illegal petrol car at night only.Car warehouse, cop gunfight in dark](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173930/classic-short-story-in-anthology-driving-illegal-petrol-car-at-night-only-car-wa)

Comment: You appear to have copied and pasted another user's answer without attribution. I assume this was accidental, but you should fix that

Comment: I'm not sure this question is about the same story. **(1)** In Robinson's story, the man with the illegal car is "middle-aged", not an "old man". **(2)** It sounds like the story described here is told from the point of view of the man with the car; in Robinson's story the cop is the first-person narrator. **(3)** Robinson's story does not have all that much "imagery about headlights on the road and the thrill of going cruising."